# Restricting dbms_sql to SELECT queries

Tags: oracle, security, plsql, sql-injection

I am writing a function similar to Tom Kyte's [`print_table`](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1035431863958), but with more output options and better formatting, etc., etc. It struck me that writing a function where you could enter arbitrary SQL with `authid currentuser` -- rather than passing a ref cursor -- was pretty dangerous! However, I need to know the column attributes and, AFAIK, there's no other way of getting this.

Is there a way, therefore, of restricting the `dbms_sql.execute` function so it only operates on `select` queries? Or, put another way, is there a way to check the type of DML being parsed through the cursor and then, for example, raise an exception if it's anything other than a `select`?

Textual analysis of the query (e.g., allowing `select` or `with`, but nothing else) wouldn't work, because you could just do `print_table('select * from dual; drop someTable');` etc...

(P.S., Oracle 10gR2, if it makes a difference.)

Comment: What makes you think that running arbitrary SELECT query is not "pretty dangerous"?

Comment: Why is it dangerous to run with `authid current_user`?  If the user has privileges to `drop someTable` and wants to drop the table, what does it matter if they execute that command directly or via your procedure?  That's the point of `authid current_user`, you're just using the user's existing privs not implicitly giving the caller additional privs.  Is this a case where the code is running as an Oracle user that has more privileges than the application user actually should (i.e. there is a three-tier application where the middle tier is calling your procedure)?

Comment: @JustinCave The user tier *should* be the one doing the calling -- and therefore be appropriately restricted by role/grants/etc. Unfortunately, while it's limited to a very small set of known and trustworthy users, there are instances where it'll be invoked (possibly wrongly) at higher levels... I was just hoping there's some additional way I can protect myself from such mistakes!

Comment: Isn't this fundamentally a non-question? Simply provide the user with desirable level of permissions.

Comment: @CleverIdeaWidgetry It has become a non-question, now that I'm aware that using Oracle's security model is the only way to apply such restrictions. Beforehand, I don't think it was much of a stretch to believe that SQL statements could be broadly classified by `dbms_sql` (or, in general): e.g., this is a `select`, that's an `update`, or a PL/SQL block, or sequence of statements, etc., etc.